# Sass passing quoted math string into mixin

Tags: sass

So I'm trying to pass a modifier into a SASS mixin:

```
$headerHeight: 40px;
@mixin hh($prop, $mod: " + 0") {
    #{$prop}: #{$headerHeight + $mod};
}

.something {
    @include hh(padding-top, " * 2"); // Should return padding-top: 80px;
}
```

I keep getting things like `padding-top: 40px + 0;` no matter how many times I try and unquote it.  Is it not possible to have the math string evaluated inside a mixin?

I've tried it without the px on $headerHeight, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I can do something like this:

```
@mixin hh($prop, $aMod: 0px, $mMod: 1) {
  #{$prop}: ($headerHeight + $aMod) * $mMod;
}
```

But I'd prefer to just be able to put any arbitrary math string in there instead of having to break up the additive and multiplicative aspects of the math.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you would have to do something like create functions that act as operators for you and call them with the `call()` function inside your mixin:

```
@function plus($i, $j: 0) {
  @return $i + $j;
}

@function times($i, $j: 0) {
  @return $i * $j;
}

$headerHeight: 40px;
@mixin hh($prop, $func, $mod) {
    #{$prop}: call($func, $headerHeight, $mod);
}

.something {
    @include hh(padding-top, 'plus', 2); // 42px
    @include hh(padding-bottom, 'times', 2); // 80px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible, you could do something like the following however to achieve the same goal:

```
$headerHeight: 40;
@mixin hh($prop, $mod, $modval) {
  @if $mod == '+' {
    #{$prop}: $headerHeight + $modval * 1px;  
  }
  @if $mod == '-' {
    #{$prop}: $headerHeight - $modval * 1px;  
  }
  @if $mod == '*' {
    #{$prop}: $headerHeight * $modval * 1px;  
  }
  @if $mod == '/' {
    #{$prop}: $headerHeight / $modval * 1px;  
  }
}

.something {
  @include hh(padding-top, '*', 2); // Should return padding-top: 80px;
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/be55fe73c307d0ad018c